# Python: how to reshape pandas dataframe with groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe containing the number of accidents for each day in a grid of dimension `NxM`. For each cell I have its coordinates `x` and `y`.

```
df
    cell   n_acc   x    y   day
0    0      5      0    1    1
1    1      2      0    2    1
2    2      0      1    1    1
3    3      1      1    2    1
4    4      8      2    0    1
5    5      0      2    1    1
6    0      0      0    1    2
7    1      3      0    2    2
8    2      7      1    1    2
9    3      2      1    2    2
10   4      0      2    0    2
11   5      0      2    1    2
```

I would like to map the total number of accidents in each cell a `NxM` dataframe or in a `NxM` array.

In the first step I did

```
dftmp = dt.group_by('cell').sum()
```

that returns the sum over all the cell.

Comment: Have you searched for `pandas`, `reshape`, and `groupby` on SO?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael it should be a `NxM` pandas dataframe or a `NxM` array

Comment: @emax - I think output DataFrame, what numbers, columns...

Comment: @jezrael as numbers the total number of accidents. My goal is to map the number of accident in a 2d plane where the cell `N_xy` corresponds to the total number of accidents in the cell of coordinates `(x,y)`